# how to show 2/12/2017 as February,2017 in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get both months and years on my axis, and therefore require the format to be like YYYY-MM. Please suggest. My existing format is 2/12/2017...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current format is a date column, this should work:

```
YearMonth = FORMAT([DateColumn];"YYYY-MM")
```

(My date format is a bit different, due to local settings, but it should work with your format/locale)

[image: Result:]